# Trying to go to the signup or log out page gives Hmm cant reach this repl

Tags: php

[image]

Don't know why it doesn't work I reviewed the code like 15 times, there are no errors, if there were it would say.
Code for signup.php :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Math Bot Web Server</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
  // The global $_POST variable allows you to access the data sent with the POST method by name
  // To access the data sent with the GET method, you can use $_GET
  $user = htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']);
  $pass  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']);
  $db = getenv('REPLIT_DB_URL');
  $user_endcode = base64_encode($user);
  $pass_encode = base64_encode($pass);
  $data = array($user => $pass);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($db, false, $context);
?>
  <form method="post" action="dashboard.php">
    <input type='hidden' name='user' value='<?php echo "$user_endcode";?>'/> 
    <input type='hidden' name='pass' value='<?php echo "$pass_encode";?>'/> 
  </form>  
  <?php
    header('/dashboard.php');
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code for log_out.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("MathBot.enzon3.repl.co"); 
exit();
?>
```

There are no errors, but when I try to access the page, the request's status code is a 502 Bad Gateway.
EDIT: Just tell me why it's broken, and I'll find out, for some of you that are asking, the headers are correct.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Is that a valid `header` value?

Comment: For the second one, it is correct, because it is an **absolute URL**. the header in signup.php is correct.